# ¿Cómo crear un campo concatenando otros dos campos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenación

Necesito crear en *MySQL* el código de un usuario concatenando, por ejemplo:

- Las 4 primeras letras de su nombre
- Las 4 primeras letras de su apellido
- Los 4 primeros dígitos de su teléfono

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO(
    CODIGO   CHAR(12)     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE   VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    APELLIDO VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    TELEFONO INT(7)       NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO USUARIO VALUES ('John','Martins',1234567);
```

Lo que busco es que al ingresar el nombre y apellido, se genere automáticamente el código del usuario y que se registre como:

```
JohnMart1234;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto.

Una es usando *Generated Columns* en *MySQL*:

- [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual: 13.1.18.8 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
    CODIGO   CHAR(12) as (concat(substring(nombre, 1, 4), substring(apellido, 1, 4))),
    NOMBRE   VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    APELLIDO VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    TELEFONO INT(7)       NOT NULL
);
```

Luego insertas valores como:

```
insert into usuario (nombre, apellido, telefono) values ('Lionel', 'Messi', 12345);
```

Y tienes en tu tabla:

```
CODIGO: LionMess
Nombre: Lionel
Apellido: Messi
Telefono: 12345
```

Otra alternativa es usar un *trigger* (pero es más trabajo y no hay ninguna ventaja).

Acá hay un [ejemplo funcionando que hice en DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tG37tucLvst7xaD4qSwbJF/0#).

Comment: Gracias por responder, alguna idea de cómo hacerlo pero en la versión 5.5?

Comment: Hola @DuffBeer - En la versión 5.5, solo con *triggers*. Lo ideal es que especifiques en tu pregunta si tienes restricciones con respecto a la versión de MySQL. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer con *triggers<sup>1</sup>* aplicando lógica en bases de datos, aunque creo que lo mejor sería que dicha lógica esté en el *software* que estás desarrollando por si en el futuro necesitas cambiar de gestor de bases de datos.

Por cierto, para concatenar varias cadenas puedes usar *concat_ws<sup>2</sup>*.

*MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual:*

1. `TRIGGER`: [24.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
2. `CONCAT_WS`: [12.5 String Functions `CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Answer (score 1):

Para ello tienes que hacer **SUBSTRING** con los valores que necesitas y luego concatenarlos.

Puedes obtener los valores que deseas ejecutando por *SQL*, `SELECT SUBSTRING(USUARIO.NOMBRE, 1,4) AS NOMBRE;` Con eso puedes obtener los 4 primeros caracteres del nombre. Solo debes cambiar el nombre del campo que necesitas obtener sus caracteres para luego concatenar con **CONCAT**.

```
SELECT CONCAT(NOMBRE_4_LETRAS, APELLIDO_4_LETRAS, CODIGO_4_LETRAS) AS CODIGO_USUARIO;
```

Puedes leer un poco más y jugar haciendo pruebas en:

- [W3Schools: MySQL CONCAT() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)
- [W3Schools: ***try MySQL*** CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_concat)